# nodejs sqlite 3 "SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed" db.run within db.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

So I am trying the following:

```js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('MyDB.db');

console.log("Initializing...")
var MyGUID = "d49dfb07-7ac9-42e7-a355-2707209baea5";
db.serialize(function() {
    db.all("SELECT Name, Status FROM MyTable WHERE MyGUID = ? ", [MyGUID], function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        db.run("UPDATE MyTable SET readOnly = 0 WHERE MyGUID = 'd49dfb07-7ac9-42e7-a355-2707209baea5'", "", function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }); 
});

db.close();
```

This results in "SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed"
Apparently I cannot run the UPDATE query within the db.all callback. But why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the second query as an argument to `db.serialize()`. Then it will wait for it to complete before returning and allowing `db.close()` to run.

```js
db.serialize(function() {
  db.all("SELECT Name, Status FROM MyTable WHERE MyGUID = ? ", [MyGUID], function(err, rows) {
    console.log(rows)
  });
  db.run("UPDATE MyTable SET readOnly = 0 WHERE MyGUID = 'd49dfb07-7ac9-42e7-a355-2707209baea5'", "", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But apparently the db.run is executed before the the callback of db.all is called. So How can I make sure that the callback of db.all is finished before the db.run is executed. For example if I would want to check for the "Name" I am fetching with the db.all and only make the db.run if the "Name" is equal to "John".

Comment: You could put the `db.close()` in the last callback.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes you don't see what's right in front of you